# What is 12 in this same pattern?

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle

7 = `31674Z`S

8 = `883011S`O

9 = `166037352U`R

10 = `434782608W`P

11 = `31701296735I`G

What would 12 be equal to in this same pattern?

Hint:

> Open your calculator.

Another hint:

> Use the trial and error method.

Comment: Is there a specific knowledge that's required, or is it trivial/not necessary? In case the 'knowledge'-tag should be used, I mean.

Comment: @Prim3numbah, no, I'd say it's not necessary. 3*rot13(V whfg znqr gur *ynfg gjb*) + 5*rot13( yrggref nf vs gurl pbhyq or zvfhaqrefgbbq vs haqrefgbbq fb, gb znxr gur chmmyr rira gevpxvre.) I've added 2 tags that I feel are relevant.

Comment: @Prim3numbah, (1+3+1)*rot13(Vf gur chmmyr ernyyl gung uneq? Pbzcner gur rqvg jvgu gur cerivbhf bar gb trg nabgure uvag. Jvgu vg, vg'f npghnyyl irel rnfl. Gb phg pbearef, lbh arrq gb thrff vg evtug.)

Comment: @Prim3numbah, 13*rot13(gur chmmyr vfa'g gung uneq. Gur obhagl'f tbvat gb rkcver fbba! Urer'f nabgure uvag: gur ahzoref ner uhtr, fb- lbh whfg unir gb thrff naq trg. Gurer'f abg rira nalguvat yvxr gur Clguntbenf gurberz gung lbh'yy unir gb nccyl, whfg fvzcyr bcrengvbaf.)

Comment: Ive tried different ways to solve it. Like using exponents, factorials etc but no progress.

Comment: @Prim3numbah, rot13(V perngrq gur chmmyr va n jnl gung abar bs lbhe gevrf pna 01110011 01101001 01101110 01100111 01101100 01100101 00101101 01101000 01100001 01101110 01100100 01100101 01100100 01101100 01111001 (`.️`-V4, fb hfr `⚡️┬─┬f.pbz` gb qrpbqr) qrsrng gur ynetr naq inthr ahzore. "snpgbevnyf"? V guvax lbh arrq gb phg pbfgf: lbh'er fcraqvat gbb zhpu sbe na bccbarag jub'f whfg n snpgbe bs lbhe frpbaq zrgubq. Gur bccbarag unf sbetbggra gung havgl vf fgeratgu; hfr vg gb qrsrng vg.)

Comment: @VarunW., I didn't want to give a hint in *just* rot13; it's not that great, so I decided to put it in a mini-puzzle. This is how I wanted to give the hint, as I feel getting the answer is so easy with it. Also, rot13 is too boring and not that great. **Why** should I stick to rot13?

Comment: @VarunW., it's the other way round. Spoilers don't spoil it for others (they don't want it to be), but my intention was to get that hint by solving another mini-puzzle. So, who wants the hint solves a simple puzzle to get it.

Comment: 3*rot13 and 5*rot13 are uhh just rot13. Anyway, it seems like we're intended to rot13(pbzovar gur gjb yrggref cre yvar) somehow, but darned if I can figure out how that leads to anything meaningful.

Comment: @EdMurphy, rot[13-6-1](Eky- qkkv zxeotm, gtj eua'rr mkz oz.)

Comment: @Prim3numbah, the bounty's going to end soon... is there any progress?

Comment: I think you may be overestimating how obvious your hints are. Feel free to answer any/all of these: Does this use A=1 B=2 etc. in some fashion? Does this involve anything more complex than addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, shifting decimal places, and/or concatenation?

Comment: @EdMurphy, yes and yes.

Comment: 13*rot13(grfgvat)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer.

Googling OEIS plus some of the numbers, I found

> https://oeis.org/A057070/internal

which led me to:

> 31674 * 26 + 19 = 7^7

> 883011 * 19 + 15 = 8^8 + 8

> 166037352 * 21 + 18 = 9^10 + 9 (corrected)

> 434782608 * 23 + 16 = 10^10

> 31701296735 * 9 + 7 = 11^11 + 11

so we're looking for values A, B, C such that

> A * B + C = 12^13 + 12 (corrected)

> B = 1 to 26

> C = 1 to 26

and apparently

> B > C

Running this through a spreadsheet gives the following options. Not sure which of these is intended to fit some additional pattern in the previous examples.

> 21398641075816 * 5 + 4 (E D) (list corrected)

> 15284743625583 * 7 + 3 (G C)

> 13374150672385 * 8 + 4 (H D)

> 11888133931009 * 9 + 3 (I C)

> 10699320537908 * 10 + 4 (J D)

> 9726655034462 * 11 + 2 (K B)

> 8230246567621 * 13 + 11 (M K)

> 7642371812791 * 14 + 10 (N J)

> 7132880358605 * 15 + 9 (O I)

> 6687075336192 * 16 + 12 (P L)

> 6293717963475 * 17 + 9 (Q I)

> 5944066965504 * 18 + 12 (R L)

> 5631221335741 * 19 + 5 (S E)

> 5349660268954 * 20 + 4 (T D)

> 5094914541861 * 21 + 3 (U C)

> 4863327517231 * 22 + 2 (V B)

> 4651878494742 * 23 + 18 (W R)

> 4458050224128 * 24 + 12 (X L)

> 4279728215163 * 25 + 9 (Y I)

> 4115123283810 * 26 + 24 (Z X)

Comment: Yessss! The first part is almost correct. But, there's a unique pattern, and most parts of your answer are wrong because of that. You're very, very close to the answer (the value of 12). Also, you have to change the order of some things.

Comment: I spotted a mistake and fixed related parts.

Comment: You're actually very close to the answer. rot13(Gurer'f abguvat yvxr O > P. Naq jung lbh unir gb svaq vf nyfb jebat. Whfg ybbx ng ubj lbh qrpvcurerq gur cnggrea.)

Comment: Well, B > C happens to be true of all six given examples. And I worked out this much simply by catching on that 8^8 [vf irel arneyl na vagrtre zhygvcyr bs] 883011, and then [fcbggvat juvpu zhygvcyr (O) naq ubj sne vg jnf bss (uvture ol P)]. If you're thinking that I worked out the opposite - why *that particular* choice of B - then no, I didn't.

Comment: rot13(Lrf, gung'f evtug, ohg gurer vf cebonoyl n irel fznyy reebe fbzrjurer. V pna'g znxr bhg ubj lbh znqr vg (rira znlor n glcb), ohg, jung lbh unir gb svaq, nppbeqvat gb lbh, vf jebat. Naq fbzr bgure cnegf bs lbhe nafjre ner jebat orpnhfr bs gung. Lbh tbg gur cnggrea evtug; lbh whfg unir gb nccyl vg naq trg gur nafjre.)

Comment: Is the error within the first five lines (equations for 7 through 11)? Because I just double-checked that (a) the large numbers match those in the original post, (b) the small numbers match the letters, and (c) the arithmetic is correct. So I have to wonder if maybe one of your edits to the original post wasn't saved as you thought it was.

Comment: rot13(Irel fbeel! V qvqa'g ernyvmr be abgvpr gung lbh unq gb svaq (a^a)*a, naq lbh sbhaq a^(a+1), juvpu vf gur fnzr. Pna lbh cyrnfr uvtuyvtug gur pbzovangvba jvgu gur zbfg cersrenoyl pbairavrag yrggre gb or gur fnzr nf 9'f pbqr?)

Comment: rot13(Sbe 9, V npghnyyl sbhaq (9^10)+9, be ((9^9)*9)+9 juvpu znl or jung lbh vagraqrq. Nyy gur ragevrf va zl svany yvfg rdhny ((12^12)*12)+12. V unir ab vqrn jung lbh zrna ol "pbairavrag".)

Comment: rot13(Fbeel, V cebonoyl cuenfrq vg jebatyl. V zrnag gur pbzovangvba va juvpu bar yrggre (gur yrggre gb zbfg/zber pbairavragyl xrrc nf vf (va 9'f pbqr, nf 9'f pbqr'f cnggrea vf gur fnzr nf 12'f), v.r., gur svefg yrggre, nf vg'f rnfvre gb svaq n pbqr sbe 12 xrrcvat gur svefg yrggre gur fnzr guna xrrcvat gur frpbaq (nf lbh unir gb svaq gur erznvaqre naq vg'f cebonoyl n gevny naq reebe zrgubq)).)

Comment: Okay, please answer yes or no to the following: Is my explanation of 9's pattern 100% correct and 100% equivalent to the explanation that you intended? Because if the answer is no, then that needs to be sorted before I can do anything useful with 12.

Comment: Yes, I think it's 100% correct if I've not made another silly mistake.

Comment: rot13(Gur guvat vf, nyy gjragl bs zl fhttrfgrq fbyhgvbaf zngpu gur fnzr cnggrea sbe 12. Fvzvyneyl, gurer ner friragrra fbyhgvbaf zngpuvat gur pbqr sbe 9 (O = 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26), naq V qba'g haqrefgnaq jul lbh cvpxrq 21 nf bccbfrq gb bar bs gur bguref.)

Comment: rot13(Lrf, nyy bs gurz zngpu, va n jnl. Ubjrire, gb znxr gur nafjre zber cerpvfr, V'z fnlvat gung lbh fubhyq hfr gur fnzr yrggre hfrq va 9'f pbqr (gur 21fg yrggre, 'H'; abg 'E' orpnhfr vg'f rnfvre gb znxr gur pbqr sbe 12 hfvat 'H' nf lbh jbhyq arrq gb qvivqr gur ahzore ol enaqbz ahzoref gb trg 'E' nf gur erznvaqre, naq vg'f zbfg cebonoyl n gevny-naq-reebe zrgubq). Nyfb, gur pbqrf lbh'ir tbg nera'g cebcreyl sbeznggrq (gur nafjre vf gur pbqr, abg gur rdhngvba).) ;)

Comment: rot13(Ohg jul? Arvgure bs gur yrggref sbe 11 vf n ercrng bs gur pbeerfcbaqvat yrggre sbe 8, abe 10 naq 7. Nyfb, nf vg unccraf, bar bs gur bgure bcgvbaf qbrf nyybj E gb or ercrngrq nf gur frpbaq ahzore. Ohg naljnl, vs jr whfg gnxr vg nf tvira gung sbe *fbzr* ernfba gur svefg yrggre sbe 12 fubhyq or H, gura gur cerpvfr nafjre vf 5094914541861H P.)

Comment: rot13(Lrf, gung'f evtug! Pna lbh cyrnfr rqvg gur nafjre gb uvtuyvtug vg? Nyfb, gur nafjre vf gur pbqr, abg gur rdhngvba.)

Comment: I can, but I'd want to also explain why the answer is that one and not any of the other ones. *Why* is it that one? (Besides just "you said so".) In particular, why is rot13(ercrngvat gur svefg yrggre sebz 9 gb 12) a thing, when it wasn't a thing elsewhere?

Comment: I thought you understood the puzzle and what I said earlier- and it should follow 9's as it's the answer, regardless of the fact that 10's letters don't *directly* match with 7's and 11's don't with 8, as it can be got by some method or the other; and what do you mean by "why is rot13(ercrngvat gur svefg yrggre sebz 9 gb 12) a thing, when it wasn't a thing elsewhere?"?

Comment: Here's what I do understand: (rot13 from here onward) N*O+P = (fbzrguvat); 1 <= O <= 26; 1 <= P <= 26; naq O > P (be, rdhvinyragyl, P vf gur erznvaqre sebz N/O; vs guvf erdhverzrag vfa'g vapyhqrq, gura gurer ner frireny zber bcgvbaf gung V qvqa'g yvfg). V unira'g svtherq bhg nal nqqvgvbany cnggrea gung aneebjf gubfr bcgvbaf qbja gb rknpgyl bar. V qvq pbafvqre ybbxvat ng O-P, juvpu (sebz gur tvira rknzcyrf) vf 7, 4, 3, 7, 2, naq (sebz gur bar gung lbh fnl vf pbeerpg) 18. Fb gung frrzf yvxr n erq ureevat.

Comment: AAAAAAA- I'm not reading that, LOL. But, the answer still is the code and not the equation.

Comment: Why not? It's your puzzle, you already know what I'm trying to figure out. And yes, I get that the answer is the code and not the equation, but (1) there's a trivial mapping between them, (2) I already reiterated the intended code in an earlier comment, and (3) I still don't understand *why* that particular equation<->code is the intended answer, and all the other equations<->codes that I listed are not. I get that you don't want to just spell out the rest of the pattern, but can you please give a hint more specific than "related to 9 and should be obvious from there"? It is *not* obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137333/discussion-between-the-amateur-coder-and-ed-murphy).

Comment: Well, that stalled out. Alas, I suspect this is as resolved as it's gonna get, unless the poster wakes up again.